# mongodb python import csv

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm trying to import csv into Mongodb, and then from Mongodb, execute command to get the data out.

This is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
db = client.test # client.database_name
collection = db.test #db.collection_name


def csv_to_json(filename, header=None):
    data = pd.read_csv(filename, header=header)
    return data.to_dict('records')

collection.insert_many(csv_to_json('test.csv'))
```

However, I had this error. What actually went wrong?

```
    operation, command, docs, check_keys, ack, opts, ctx)

InvalidDocument: documents must have only string keys, key was 0
```

Answer (score 0):

By default `read_csv()` will index the dataframe rows and columns from zero. The `to_dict()` method will then create a list of dicts that have a numeric key. Numeric keys aren't allowed in MongoDB; hence the problem you are seeing.

So, assuming your csv file looks like:

```
Field1,Field2
a,x
b,y
c,z
```

Then the only change you need to make is:

```
collection.insert_many(csv_to_json('test.csv', header=0))
```

This will tell pandas to create an index based on the header row which will then be the keys for each field in the document.

```
pprint.pprint(list(collection.find({}, {'_id': 0})))
```

gives:

```
[{'Field1': 'a', 'Field2': 'x'},
 {'Field1': 'b', 'Field2': 'y'},
 {'Field1': 'c', 'Field2': 'z'}]
```